# solr join multivalue fields query in cores

Tags: solr

I have two cores in solr, master and child.

Some sample data on master core is like

```
{master_id:1,child_ids:[123,456]}
```

And sample data on child core is like

```
[{child_id:123,"Name":"ABC Ltd"},{child_id:456,"Name":"xyz ltd"}]
```

child_ids in master core is multivalue field so name contains "s" in master core.

How can I join these two cores where I will get a result like

```
master_id,child_id,name
1,123,"ABC Ltd"
1,456,"xyz ltd"
```

Answer (score 2):

The join query parser in Solr can't include fields from both sides of the join, but by using a [Streaming Expression](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/streaming-expressions.html) you can create a Stream that returns complete documents from both sides.

A Streaming Expression which gives the result you're looking could be:

```
hashJoin(
  search(joinahoy, q=child_id:[* TO *], fl="child_id,Name", sort="child_id asc"),  
  hashed=cartesianProduct(
    search(joinahoy, q=master_id:[* TO *], fl="master_id,child_ids", sort="master_id asc"),
    child_ids
  ),
  on="child_id=child_ids"
)
```

The `hashJoin` decorator takes two streams and returns a document with the fields from both. A hashJoin will read the complete stream on the right side (given through `hashed`) into memory, then look up those values when joining them to the left side (the first query).

You might be able to use a `innerJoin` decorator instead with a sort specification on the `cartesianProduct` decorator, but I couldn't get that to work when experimenting.

The `cartesianProduct` decorator returns one document for each value in the multi valued field (`child_ids`) for the master document.

The result is a set of JSON documents that maps to the format you wanted:

```
{
  "result-set": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "master_id": 1,
        "child_id": 123,
        "child_ids": 123,
        "Name": [
          "ABC Ltd"
        ]
      },
      {
        "master_id": 1,
        "child_id": 456,
        "child_ids": 456,
        "Name": [
          "xyz ltd"
        ]
      },
      {
        "EOF": true,
        "RESPONSE_TIME": 9
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can wrap the `hashJoin` in a `select` decorator if you don't want both child id fields returned.

Answer (score -1):

There is no join option(between 2 cores) in solr directly.The best option would be making a single core instead of two. That can be achieved simply by adding an extra field(master_id) in child core.